# Make pacemaker retry failed resources

Tags: linux, pacemaker, linux-ha

I would like to get pacemaker to retry starting my resource

```
primitive Imq ocf:example:imq \
   op monitor on-fail="restart" interval="10s" \
   op start interval="0" timeout="60s" on-fail="restart" \
   meta failure-timeout="30s"
```

Note that this resource is pinned to the first node via

```
location location_Imq Imq inf: vm1
location location_Imq1 Imq -inf: vm2
```

Currently if I break something that stops this resource from starting the failure count returns INFINITY and stops attempting to restart the service.

I would like to never give up on the resource so that once the intermittent issue clears its self the resource restarts and resumes service.

Using pacemaker 1.0 on CentOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the solution is quite simple all that is needed is to set 'start-failure-is-fatal' to `false`.

```
crm configure property start-failure-is-fatal=false
```

This is a global option and it's default is `true` hence my failing resource.

[Pacemaker configuration reference](http://www.clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.0/html-single/Pacemaker_Explained/index.html#id2030220)